# JMeter: How to count number of occurrences in array and add sum of it in POST DATA?

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, sum

This is json response

```html
{"description":null,"points":[1,0],"description":null,"points":[0,0],"description":null,"points":[1,0],"description":null,"points":[1,1],"description":null,"points":[1,0],}
```

And here I need to add sum of first value of array to post json body data:

```html
   
"points":4  // i.e: [1,0][0,0][1,0][1,1][1,0]   value of first in array 1+0+1+1+1=4
```

How may I add sum of these ones to variable "points"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is json response

this is not true, you can check yourself using any online (or offline) [JSON
validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Whatever, you can still extract the numbers you're looking for using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and the following Groovy code:

```
log.info('Response: ' + prev.getResponseDataAsString())
def sum = 0
(prev.getResponseDataAsString() =~ /\[(\d+),/).eachWithIndex { match, idx ->
    log.info('Match # ' + idx + ', extracted number: ' + match[1] + ' from ' + match)
    sum += match[1] as int
}
log.info('Sum of extracted values: ' + sum)
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([points: sum]).toPrettyString())
log.info('Generated payload:\n' + vars.get('payload'))
```

[image]

References:

- `prev` is a shorthand for [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance
- `=~` is the [Find Operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_find_operator) allowing evaluating [regular expressions](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/groovy-regular-expressions-the-definitive-guide/)
- [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) is a helper class for [producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)

See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter

Comment: I just want "points":4 and not the { }. How may I get it?

Comment: I'm not going to follow your "updated post body", as an exception: change `vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([points: sum]).toPrettyString())` to `vars.put('payload', "points: " + sum)`

Comment: now it prints: points: 4 instead of "points":4